# Flexbox: Image forcing list items out of container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Using flexbox can you wrap text around an image? The image `.avatar` is forcing the list at the bottom, `.user_contact_details` out of the containing div. If I change the image size then it brings the text back in, but I can't do that.

Thanks

```css
    body {
      font-size: 16px;
      font-family: 'Arial';
      margin: 10px;
    }
    .profile_card_container {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: space-between;
      width: 255px;
      height: 150px;
      padding: 10px;
      border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #ededed;
    }
    .user_name {
      font-family: 'Arial';
      color: #2f353f;
    }
    .user_job_title {
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #72bcd4;
    }
    .user_contact_details {
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    .user_contact_details ul {
      list-style-type: none;
    }
    .user_contact_details ul li i {
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #72bcd4;
      padding-right: 10px;
    }
    .user_contact_details ul li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #72bcd4;
    }
    .avatar {
      float: right;
      width: 106px;
      height: 106px;
      background-color: blue;/*just for snippet*/
      /*url('images/avatar.png') no-repeat;*/
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="profile_card_container">
    <div class="user_details">
      <span class="user_name">User Name</span>
      <br /><span class="user_job_title">Job Title</span>
    </div>
    <div class="avatar">
    </div>
    <div class="user_contact_details">
      <ul>
        <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Location</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>&nbsp;0101 101 01 01</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i><a href="mailto:user.name@mail-longemail.co.uk">user.name@mail-longemail.co.uk</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flex` doesn't wrap text around image, so I removed it and just made a minor markup change where I moved your avatar to be the first child.

By adding padding to the user contacts and its item it now looks like the layout in your image.

Based on the markup structure, the outcome can differ quite a lot when the content, and each item length, changes, therefore a more clear description is necessary to suggest a fully working solution.

*Side note on made comment: If this still won't line up in your local version, as it does in this snippet, some more code of yours likely override the CSS than the one we have access to. Further more, the code we present shows how to, and you need to understand how to apply that to your own.*

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Bliss2Regular';
  margin: 10px;
}
.profile_card_container {
  width: 255px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #ededed;
}
.user_details {
}
.user_name {
  font-family: 'Bliss2Bold';
  color: #2f353f;
}
.user_job_title {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #72bcd4;
}
.user_contact_details {
  padding-top: 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.user_contact_details ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.user_contact_details ul li {
  padding-top: 12px;
}
.user_contact_details ul li i {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #72bcd4;
}
.user_contact_details ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #72bcd4;
}
.avatar {
  float: right;
  width: 106px;
  height: 106px;
  background-color: blue;
  /*url('images/avatar.png') no-repeat;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="profile_card_container">

  <div class="user_details">
    <div class="avatar"></div>
    <div class="user_name">User Name</div>
    <div class="user_job_title">Job Title</div>
    <div class="user_contact_details">
      <ul>
        <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>Location</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>0101 101 01 01</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i><a href="mailto:user.name@mail-longemail.co.uk">user.name@mail-longemail.co.uk</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: @waynejames So I updated based on your comments and added it how you asked, then you still picked another answer which was the same as my first answer? ... would have been more appropriate to let me know so I could switch back to the `flex` I already posted.

Comment: No sorry, I accepted your answer first, then the other as I didn't know that would unmark yours, both answers are correct, the other (and your original) are as close as it could get using flex, but I'm using your updated code based on your advice and just updated to mark your answer as correct. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @waynejames No problem, thanks for clarifying what happened.

Answer (score 1):

you have to watch out with your nesting if you put the text in a div and the picture in one div and then the two dis in a parent div and you give him flexbox it should work :)

```css
   body {
      font-size: 16px;
      font-family: 'Bliss2Regular';
      margin: 10px;
    }
    .profile_card_container {
      display: flex;
      /*flex-wrap: wrap;*/
      justify-content: space-between;
      width: 255px;
      height: 150px;
      padding: 10px;
      border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #ededed;
    }
    .user_details{
      width:100%;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .test{
      display:flex;
      flex-direction:column;
     text-align: center;
    }
    .user_name {
      font-family: 'Bliss2Bold';
      color: #2f353f;
    }
    .user_job_title {
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #72bcd4;
    }
    .user_contact_details {
      font-size: 12px;
      
    }
    .user_contact_details ul {
      list-style-type: none;
       padding: 0px;
    }
    .user_contact_details ul li i {
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #72bcd4;
    }
    .user_contact_details ul li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #72bcd4;
    }
    .avatar {
      /*float: right;*/
      width: 106px;
      height: 106px;
      background:url('http://lorempixel.com/106/106/cats') no-repeat;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="profile_card_container">
  <div class="test">
    <div class="user_details">
      <span class="user_name">User Name</span>
      <br /><span class="user_job_title">Job Title</span>
    </div>
    <div class="user_contact_details">
      <ul>
        <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Location</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>&nbsp;0101 101 01 01</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i><a href="mailto:user.name@mail-longemail.co.uk">user.name@mail-longemail.co.uk</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
     </div>
     <div class="avatar">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```